# Deduction of a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am wondering what it means to "find a deduction for a tautology, say $((\neg(\neg A_0))\rightarrow A_0).$

I'm not really sure what a deduction is. Is it a sequence of formulas that satisfy the axioms for a proof?

**$\Gamma$ proof axioms**

(Group I axioms)

(1) $((ϕ_1 → (ϕ_2 → ϕ_3)) → ((ϕ_1 → ϕ_2) → (ϕ_1 → ϕ_3)))$

(2) $(ϕ_1 → ϕ_1)$

(3) $(ϕ_1 → (ϕ_2 → ϕ_1))$

(Group II axioms)

(1) $(ϕ_1 → ((¬ϕ_1) → ϕ_2))$

(Group III axioms)

(1) $(((¬ϕ_1) → ϕ_1) → ϕ_1)$

(Group IV axioms)

(1) $((¬ϕ_1) → (ϕ_1 → ϕ_2))$

(2) $(ϕ_1 → ((¬ϕ_2) → (¬(ϕ_1 → ϕ_2))))$

**Definition of proof:**

Suppose that
$s = \langleϕ_1, . . . , ϕ_n\rangle$
is a finite sequence of propositional formulas. The finite sequence s is a
Γ-proof if for each i ≤ n at least one of

$a) ϕ_i ∈ Γ;$ or

$b) ϕ_i$
is a logical axiom; or

c) there exist $j_1 < i$ and $j_2 < i$ such that
$ϕ_{j_2} = (ϕ_{j_1} → ϕ_i)$.

where $\Gamma\subseteq \mathcal{L_0}$

**Definition of $\mathcal{L}_0$**

$\mathcal{L}_0$ is the set of all formulas of the form

a)$A_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $A_n$ is a propositional symbol.

b)$\phi\rightarrow \theta $,  where $\phi,\theta\in \mathcal{L}_0$

c)$\neg\phi,$ where $\phi \in \mathcal{L}_0$.

Comment: It seems that the answer to your question is contained in the new information that you added. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is quite easy with the *Deduction Theorem*.

The theorem can be proved [see Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), page 37] with axioms Group I (Axiom (2) is provable from (1) and (3)).

> *Lemma* : $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \sigma) \vdash \psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \sigma)$

*Proof*

*i)* $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \sigma)$ --- assumed

*ii)* $\varphi$ --- assumed

*iii)* $\psi$ --- Assumed

*iv)* $\psi \rightarrow \sigma$ --- from i) and ii) by *modus ponens*

*v)* $\sigma$ --- from iii) and iv) by *mp*

*vi)* $\varphi \rightarrow \sigma$ --- from ii) and v) by *Deduction Th*

*vii)* $\psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \sigma)$ --- from iii) and vi) by *Deduction Th*.

---

Now we will prove :

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$

*Proof*

*i)* $\vdash \lnot \varphi \rightarrow (\lnot \lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$ --- from Axiom (1) Group II : $ϕ_1→((¬ϕ_1)→ϕ_2)$, with $\lnot \varphi$ in place of $ϕ_1$ and $\varphi$ in place of $ϕ_2$

*ii)* $\vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi \rightarrow (\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$ --- from *Lemma* above and i)

*iii)* $\lnot \lnot \varphi \vdash (\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$ --- from iii), assuming $\lnot \lnot \varphi$

*iv)* $\vdash (\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow \varphi$  --- from Axiom (1) Group III : $((¬ϕ_1)→ϕ_1)→ϕ_1$ with $\varphi$ in place of $ϕ_1$

*v)* $\lnot \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi$ --- from iii) and iv) by *mp*

> > *vi)* $\vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ --- from v) by *DT*.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it when I head back home. Yeah, the problem was that I was trying to prove the statement without deduction theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever one mentions *deductions*, one has a proof system in mind. In your case, it is probably what is known as a Hilbert-style proof system. A Hilbert-style proof system consists of a set of axioms and rules (actually axioms are a special case of rules, ones without any premises). A deduction is a set of statements (propositions) called *lines*, where each one is either an axiom or follows by a rule from previous lines.

Each axiom or rule is more properly a *scheme* of axioms or rules, a concept best explained by an example. A common axiom is $\varphi \to \varphi$. This means that for *every* formula $\varphi$, $\varphi \to \varphi$ is an axiom. For example, $p \to q$ is a formula, so $(p \to q) \to (p \to q)$ is an instance of the axiom scheme $\varphi \to \varphi$. An example of a derivation rule is Modus Ponens: Given $\varphi$ and $\varphi \to \psi$, deduce $\psi$.

A deduction of a tautology like $\lnot\lnot A \to A$ is a concept that depends on the proof system. Given a proof system, it is a sequence of lines, each either an axiom or follows by a rule from previous lines, where the last line is the required tautology. Since you haven't specified a proof system, I can't help you any further.

Comment: I have posted the axioms for the proof system.

Comment: Now that I have explained what a deduction is, hopefully you can take a stab at it on your own.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll solve the problem for myself. Thanks for clarifying what I need to solve for.

Comment: I still can't seem to find the right initial setup(i.e. the correct initial formulas based off the axioms to deduce it). Would you mind providing another hint.

Comment: My initial attempt was to show $((\neg(\neg A_0))\rightarrow((\neg(\neg A_0))\rightarrow A_0)$ could be a proof for $\Gamma$. Then using axiom 1, in group I, I where $\phi_0=\phi_1=(\neg(\neg A_0))$ and $\phi_3=A_0$ I could then infer $((\neg(\neg A_0))\rightarrow A_0)$. But I can't seem to establish the initial formula from the axioms.

Comment: I suggest you keep trying.

Comment: Are we allowed to assume $\Gamma\vdash(\neg(\neg A_0))$?

Comment: Or are we supposed to derive it completely from the axioms and by inference?

Comment: You cannot assume $\lnot \lnot A_0$ since it's not necessarily true. You can only assume axioms. The deduction theorem for a proof system states that if assuming $\varphi$ you can prove $\psi$, then you can also prove $\varphi \to \psi$. But without using this theorem, the pattern of proof you're suggesting doesn't work.

Comment: I have attempted other ways to get the derivation, but my efforts have been fruitless. I don't believe spending more time on the problem will be productive at this point. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof system is probably common, so you should be able to find the answer on the internet. Otherwise, I am in no better position than you for this type of question. Just spend more time on it.